# Does VSCode have a way to start a selection?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In some editors it's possible to *start a selection* and then do other commands. Example: imagine you have this text

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

You move the cursor to the beginning of `quick` and then *start a selection*. You then search for `jumps`, your selection is now `quick brown fox` , you press right 5 times, your selection is now `quick brown fox jumps`. You then search for `lazy`. Your selection is now `quick brown fox jump over the`  etc....

Does VSCode have any way to do this? Note: the commands might not just be search related, for example, start selection, go to matching paren. Or start selection, search for `foo`, move cursor right 3, search for matching brace, search for `bar`, search for matching paren, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) v1.7.0

It has a command: `selectby.mark`

The first time you call the function it remembers the start position of the current selections.

The second mark it creates selections from the marked (stored) positions to the current **active** positions of the current selections.

If the number of cursors differ it shows a warning.

You can create a key binding for this command or call it from the Command Palette.

If you modify the file after the first mark you get some undefined behavior/selections.

Currently they are not bound to the particular editor/file so you can use cursor positions from one file (first mark) in another file (second mark)

You can use a second mark to view the selections up to now. Follow it by an immediate first mark to remember the selection starts if you want to continue to modify the cursor positions.

You can combine it with the `moveby.regex` command of the same extension to move the cursors by a search for a regular expression.

I will try to add markers (decoration) on the stored positions.